# Javascript macro: implementing F# style forward pipe operator

Tags: javascript, macros, higher-order-functions, sweet.js

I want to implement a higher order function (`hof`) that essentially works like F# style forward-pipe operator (passes a value as the first argument to another function, `myFunc`). The only way I can think of is this:

```
function hof(val, myFunc, args_array) {...}
```

where `args_array` is the array of arguments for the call to `myFunc` (excluding the first argument, since that's going to be `val`)

But this doesn't look very elegant to me. Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: I found this on github https://gist.github.com/aaronpowell/d5ffaf78666f2b8fb033. But I don't really understand what the `sweet.js` code is doing. It'd be very helpful if you could annotate the code, specifically:

```
case infix { $val | _ $fn($args (,) ...) } => {
    return #{
        ($fn.length <= [$args (,) ...].length + 1 ? $fn($args (,) ..., $val) : $fn.bind(null, $args (,) ..., $val))
    }
}

case infix { $val | _ $fn } => {
    return #{
        ($fn.length <= 1 ? $fn($val) : $fn.bind(null, $val))
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't really do this with the syntax you provide because `hof()` never sees the `myFunc` function object; you are invoking `myFunc` directly and passing the return value to `hof`.

Comment: It's not really clear what your objective is. It would help if you could give us a concrete example. At the moment, it sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: yep, I realize that. I modified the title/tags. Any suggestions?

Comment: @tldr Well, what do you think of the answers so far? There's some decent stuff down there, and I think taking on a whole new framework just for this one feature might be a bit much. I don't know anything about Sweet.js and can't help you there. And you shouldn't completely change the scope of your question after you've already received 7 answers. Please open a new question if you want to ask about macros.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something like the F# pipeline operator, I think your best bet is either this approach that you had in your post:

```
hof(val, myFunc, [arg1, arg2, arg3]);
```

or this:

```
hof(val, myFunc, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

The first one can be implemented like this:

```
function hof(val, func, args) {
    func.apply(this, [val].concat(args || []));
}
```

The second one can be implemented like this:

```
function hof(val, func) {
    func.apply(this, [val].concat(Array.prototype.slice(arguments, 2));
}
```

But that all leaves the question of why you wouldn't just call the function in a normal way:

```
myFunc(val, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify what I'm trying to do. Please let me know if it's still not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this called [*Currying*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)?

Anyhow, here's a rubbish example, I'm sure there are better examples if you [search](https://www.google.com.au/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=zpcOVLuKEcvC8geiiYGICQ#q=javascript+currying):

```
function myCurry() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    var fn = args.splice(0,1)[0];
    return function(arg) {
      var a = [].concat(arg, args);
      return fn.apply(this, a);
    };
}

// Just sums the supplied arguments, initial set are 1,2,3
var fn = myCurry(function(){
                   var sum = 0;
                   for (var i=0, iLen=arguments.length; i<iLen; i++) {

                     // Show args in sequence - 4, 1, 2, 3
                     console.log('arguments ' + i + ': ' + arguments[i]);
                     sum += arguments[i];
                   }
                   return sum;
                }, 1,2,3);

// Provide an extra argument 4
console.log(fn(4)); // 10
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't even know about currying. So I can define the higher order function like so: hof(val, fn) {return fn(val)}, and call it like so: hof(val, curry(myFunc)(arg1, arg2, arg3)). That is indeed a much more elegant solution!

Comment: @tldr Still not sure I see the point of having `hof` at all. Why not just use `curry(myFunc)(arg1, arg2, arg3)(val)`, or better yet, why not just use `myFunc(val, arg1, arg2, arg3)` in the first place?

Comment: because I want the hofs to be chainable, they pipe the result of the last operation to the next myFunc. The way you describe it, it's not chainable.

Answer (score 1):

Sweet.js macros are simple, they only look cryptic at first sight.

A forward pipe in F# language, infix operator `|>` applies function on the right to the result of the expression on the left.

New syntax should look like this(`|>` macro):

```js
var seven = 7;
var outcome = 3 |> plus(seven) |> divideBy(2); // outcome must be 5
```

The pipe macro must append argument to the function, so that after expansion functions would look like this: `plus(seven, 3)`.

The sweet.js macro [in the question](https://gist.github.com/aaronpowell/d5ffaf78666f2b8fb033) works in simplest cases.

Main part is in this snippet `return #{ /** macro expansion template */ }`.
It contains javascript that is executed in compile time(sweet.js) returning text that is a code for a macro expansion.
The result of compilation:

```
var outcome$633 = plus.length <= [seven].length + 1 ? plus(seven, 5) : plus.bind(null, seven, 5);
```

[The `length` of a function in js is its number of expected positional arguments](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length).

A sofisticated macro that allows using functions contained in objects(dot notation):

```
macro (|>) {
  case infix { $val | _ $fn(.)... ( $args(,)... ) } => {
    return #{
      ($fn(.)....length <= [$args(,)...].length + 1 ? $fn(.)...( $args(,)..., $val) : $fn(.)....bind(null, $args(,)..., $val))
    }
  }

  case infix { $val | _ $fn($args ...) } => {
    return #{
      ($fn.length <= [$args ...].length + 1 ? $fn($args ..., $val) : $fn.bind(null, $args ..., $val))
    }
  }

  case infix { $val | _ $fn(.)... } => {
    return #{
      ($fn(.)....length <= 1 ? $fn(.)...($val) : $fn(.)....bind(null, $val))
    }
  }
}
```

One restriction/requirement of this macro is to omit parens `()` if a function in a pipeline does not take arguments.

Line `var outcome = 5 |> plus(seven) |> obj.subObj.func;` expands to this nested ternary operator expression in js:

`var outcome$640 = obj.subObj.func.length <= 1 ? obj.subObj.func(plus.length <= [seven].length + 1 ? plus(seven, 5) : plus.bind(null, seven, 5)) : obj.subObj.func.bind(null, plus.length <= [seven].length + 1 ? plus(seven, 5) : plus.bind(null, seven, 5));`

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, this becomes quite compact:

```
var hof = (fn, ...params) => (...addtl) => fn(...parms, ...addtl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use a closure for this kind of wrapping:

```
function callf(f, count) {
    for (var i=0; i<count; i++) {
        f(i);
    }
}

function g(x, y) {
    console.log("called g(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
}

callf(function(x) { g(x, "hey!"); }, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the first call to myFunc return another function that accepts a single parameter. Then, when you do your initial call `hof(val, myFunc(arg1, arg2, arg3));`, that function is returned, and it only needs one more argument, `val` to finish executing, which is provided by `hof`.

```
function hof(val, func){
  func(val);
}

function myFunc(arg1, arg2, arg3){
  return function(val){
    // do something with val, arg1, arg2, arg3 here
  }
}

hof(val, myFunc(arg1, arg2, arg3));
```

---

## Simple

If what you said is true, you could use the following code, but i don't see a point since you can run myFunc directly.

```
function myFunc(val, arg1, arg2, arg3){
  // do something
}

function hof(val, myfunc, arg1, arg2, arg3){
  return myFunc(val, arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
```

---

## Curry

```
function customCurry(func){
  var args = [];
  var result;

  return function(){
    var l = arguments.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < l; i++){
        if(args.length > 3) break;
        args.push(arguments[i]);
    }

    if(args.length > 3){
        return result = func(args[3], args[0], args[1], args[2]);
    }
  }
}

var preloaded = customCurry(myFunc)(arg1, arg2, arg3);

hof(val, myFunc);

function hof(val, func){
    func(val);
}
```

Comment: myFunc is already defined as taking 4 arguments and doing something (it doesn't return a function). Sorry if it wasn't clear from the question, I've edited it for clarification.

Comment: I need a better idea of what exactly you're trying to do because this implementation doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

ecma5 added *Function.bind()*, which also curries:

```
 myFunc2=myFunc.bind(this, val, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

if you want a re-usable generic function to make *bind()* a little easier:

```
 function hof(f, args){ return f.bind.apply(f, [this].concat(args));}
```

which returns a new function, parameters pre-filled with the previously passed value(s). Passing more arguments will shift them to the right, and you can access all of them via the *arguments* keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use an example.

Suppose you had a simple function to sum up numbers:

```
var sum = function() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).reduce(function(sum, value) {
        return sum + value;
    }, 0);
};
```

You can't simply call it by passing the arguments in and then passing that to another function because it will evaluate the function, so we need to create a wrapper around the function to shift the arguments across:

```
var sumWrapper = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function() {
        var innerArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).concat(args);
        return sum.apply(null, innerArgs);
    }
};
```

We can then create your higher order function (assume the last argument is the function in question):

```
var higherOrderSum = function() {
    return arguments[arguments.length - 1].apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, arguments.length - 1));
};
```

Usage:

```
alert(higherOrderSum(3, 4, sumWrapper(1, 2, 3)));
```